# How to get number of rows of a PostgreSQL cursor?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-cursor

I have a cursor created using the `WITH HOLD` option that allows the cursor to be used for subsequent transactions.

I would like to retrieve the number of rows that can be fetched by the cursor. Since the rows represented by a held cursor are copied into a temporary file or memory area, I am wondering if it is possible to retrieve that number in a straightforward way or if the only solution is to fetch all the records to count them.

In that case, a `MOVE FORWARD ALL FROM <cursor>` statement returns `MOVE x`. Where x is
the number moved.  The result is a command tag written to stdout, and I do not know how to retrieve that value in a pgsql function. `GET DIAGNOSTICS <var> := ROW_COUNT` only works for `FETCH` but not `MOVE`.

Here is a solution proposal, how do you think I can improve it ? (and is it possible to use `MOVE` instead of `FETCH` to retrieve the x value ?)

```
-- Function returning the number of rows available in the cursor
CREATE FUNCTION get_cursor_size(_cursor_name TEXT)
    RETURNS TEXT AS
$func$
DECLARE
    _n_rows int;
BEGIN
    -- Set cursor at the end of records
    EXECUTE format('FETCH FORWARD ALL FROM %I', _cursor_name);

    -- Retrieve number of rows
    GET DIAGNOSTICS _n_rows := ROW_COUNT;

    -- Set cursor at the beginning
    EXECUTE format('MOVE ABSOLUTE 0 FROM %I', _cursor_name);
    RETURN _n_rows;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to do that in PL/pgSQL.

As a workaround, you could define the cursor so that it includes a row number:

```
DECLARE c CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
SELECT *, row_number() OVER ()
FROM (SELECT /* your original query */) AS s;
```

That is only marginally more expensive than the original query, and it allows you to position the cursor on the last row with `MOVE` and retrieve the `row_number`, which is the total number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use `MOVE` instead of `FETCH` to count the records in a cursor, with slightly improved performance. As it turns out we can indeed retrieve `ROW_COUNT` diagnostics from a `MOVE` cursor statement.

**GOTCHA:** Using `EXECUTE` does not update the `GET DIAGNOSTICS` for `MOVE` while it does for `FETCH`, and neither statements will update the `FOUND` variable.

This is not clearly stipulated in [the PostgreSQL documentanion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) per se, but considering that `MOVE` does not produce any actual results it might make sense enough to be excused.

**NOTE:** The following examples do not reset the cursor position back to 0 as with the original example, allowing the function to be used with [all cursor types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/plpgsql-cursors.html) especially `NO SCROLL` cursors which will reject backward movement by raising an error.

### Using `MOVE` instead of `FETCH`

The holy grail of PostgreSQL cursor record count methods we've all been waiting for. Modify the function to take a `refcursor` as argument and instead execute the `MOVE` cursor statement directly which then makes `ROW_COUNT` available.

```sql
-- Function returning the number of rows available in the cursor
CREATE FUNCTION get_cursor_size(_cursor refcursor)
    RETURNS TEXT AS
$func$
DECLARE
    _n_rows int;
BEGIN
    -- Set cursor at the end of records
    MOVE FORWARD ALL FROM _cursor;
    -- Retrieve number of rows
    GET DIAGNOSTICS _n_rows := ROW_COUNT;

    RETURN _n_rows;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

### Alternative approaches using `MOVE`

Provided here for completion.

Another approach is to `LOOP` through the cursor until `FOUND` returns falsey, however **this approach is notably slower** than even the `FETCH ALL` method from the original example in the question.

```sql
-- Increment the cursor position and count the rows
CREATE FUNCTION get_cursor_size(_cursor refcursor)
    RETURNS TEXT AS
$func$
DECLARE
    _n_rows int := 0;
begin
    LOOP
        -- Move cursor position
        MOVE FORWARD 1 IN _cursor;
        -- While not found
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
        -- Increment counter
        _n_rows := _n_rows + 1;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN _n_rows;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Increasing the step size does improve performance but the result will be rounded up because `FOUND` will report success if the cursor has moved at all. To rectify this we can look up `ROW_COUNT` and increment by the actual amount moved instead.

```sql
-- Count the actual number of rows incremented
CREATE FUNCTION get_cursor_size(_cursor refcursor)
    RETURNS TEXT AS
$func$
DECLARE
    _n_rows int := 0;
    _move_count int;
begin
    LOOP
        -- Move cursor position
        MOVE FORWARD 100 IN _cursor;
        -- Until not found
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
        -- Increment counter
        GET DIAGNOSTICS _move_count := ROW_COUNT;
        _n_rows := _n_rows + _move_count;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN _n_rows;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

With 50,000 records I had to increase the step size to 1000 before I noticed any improvement over `FETCH ALL` so unless there is something else worth doing simultaneously the incremental approach is less optimal.

### Passing cursor functions

We will probably want to use this with cursor producing functions, like:

```sql
-- Get a reference cursor
CREATE FUNCTION get_refcursor()
    RETURNS refcursor AS
$func$
DECLARE
    return_cursor refcursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN return_cursor FOR SELECT 'One Record';
    RETURN return_cursor;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

We can simplify this by using an `OUT` argument instead allowing us to omit both the declaration block and return statement, see [the Create Function documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html).

```sql
-- Get a reference cursor
CREATE FUNCTION get_refcursor(OUT return_cursor refcursor)
    RETURNS refcursor AS
$func$
BEGIN
    OPEN return_cursor FOR SELECT 'One Record';
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Using one of our get cursor functions we can now easily count the number of returned cursor records (only 1) by passing the function as argument.

```sql
SELECT get_cursor_size(get_refcursor());
```

nJoy!