# Return column names from CTE, even if it's empty

Tags: postgresql, optimization, pagination, common-table-expression

I built a dynamic query that returns

1. Total count of entries in CTE
2. Paginated entries from CTE
3. List of column names used in CTE
4. Requested page size and page number

The beauty of in returning total count + pagination in a single roundtrip. And you can insert any CTE in it (in my case CTEs are built dynamically on backend)

My issue is that when CTE has 0 rows (e.g. where condition is not satisfied) an outer query is empty as well and I can't extract column names. How can I fix it?

```
with "cte" as (
select...)
select
    (
    select
        array_agg(column_name)
    from
        (
        select
            jsonb_object_keys(to_jsonb(cte)) as column_name) as column_names) as "ColumnNames",
    COUNT(*) over() as "TotalCount",
    (
    select
        array_agg(cte_subquery)
    from
        (
        select
            *
        from
            cte offset 30
        limit 15) as cte_subquery) as "PaginatedEntries",
    3 as "PageNumber",
    15 as "PageSize"
from
    "cte"
limit 1
```

Fiddle:
https://sqlize.online/sql/psql15/e5cd43dff492f9143e725c97cc6e0199/

Expected result

```
+-------------+------------+------------------+------------+----------+
|  ColumnNames | TotalCount | PaginatedEntries | PageNumber | PageSize |
+--------------+------------+------------------+------------+----------+
| {id,age,name,email} | 0   |         {}       |          3 |       15 |
+--------------+------------+------------------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Please show an example we can run.

Comment: Sure: https://sqlize.online/sql/psql15/3629e076ae89d8fdc8990012d1f1b469/

Comment: Please post the expected results of your example data, as text - **no images**.

Comment: Sure, I added it to the post

Comment: [Some clients](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-SELECT-INFO) expose each of these out of the box and offer a built-in pagination mechanism. What client or client library do you use? Or are you building one? Note that unless you explicitly order the rows in your `cte`, this pagination will be unreliable: without `order by` clause the order is purely accidental. It might *happen* to remain unchanged for some time, but it is not guaranteed. Also, unless you re-use the snapshot of your data by staying in a transaction, pages won't be consistent

Comment: I use EF Core & SqlKata. I have not found any way yet to get paginated entries + total_count + column_names using a single query, thus my attempt here. Order is specified in CTE, right, this query is made to be universal, so that any external query could be processed by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find column names of all existing relations in [`information_schema.columns`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html) system view. You can get them in a separate CTE, then `left join...on true` with that ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/yv9yz-Jz)).

Since you aim to inject the query and you're interested in whatever columns it turns out to have - which might not correspond to any specific table - you can do a similar thing the same with your current `jsonb_object_keys()` approach: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/YFVgyEuP)

```sql
with 
 cte   as (select * from dummy_table where true)
,cte_1 as (select * from (values (1)) as a(" ") left join cte on true limit 1)  
,cte_column_names("ColumnNames") as 
( select array_agg(column_name)
  from (select jsonb_object_keys(to_jsonb(cte_1)) as column_name
        from cte_1 offset 1) a)
,cte_paginated_entries("PaginatedEntries") as 
(select jsonb_agg(cte_subquery)
     from (select * from cte offset 0 limit 15) as cte_subquery)
select
    cn."ColumnNames"
  , COUNT(*) over() -(case when pe."PaginatedEntries" is null then 1 else 0 end) as "TotalCount" 
  , coalesce(pe."PaginatedEntries",'[]'::jsonb)
  , 3 as "PageNumber"
  , 15 as "PageSize"
from cte_column_names cn 
  left join cte on true 
  left join cte_paginated_entries pe on true
limit 1
```

1. In `cte_1` a `left join` with a single dummy value generates a row that starts with that value and keeps all `cte` fields filled with `null`. This solves your problem of not having a row at all to read column names from.
2. That lets you then pass it to your field name aggregation, where     `offset 1` skips the previously added dummy field.
3. This leaves your `count(*) over ()` trick that wants to claim there's a non-zero total count, still seeing the row with the column names whenever there were no actual rows.
4. A `case` can correct that: even if there was a single column with a null, in that scenario "PaginatedEntries" will not be null but a an array with a null in it, which doesn't match the `is null` case.
5. Added `coalesce` to match your expected output.

You clarified you actually do make sure there's `order by` that keeps paging order consistent. Note that you still need the state to also stay consistent: you can hold on to the table snapshot by issuing subsequent page queries within the same transaction.

This isn't very pretty but it works the way you intended. Still, you might want to consider using [`cursors` and cursor-returning functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66334521/5298879) as well as session-specific temp tables, all of which could get you all that info in a single round-trip a bit more cleanly. At the moment, your pagination keeps re-evaluating things it otherwise wouldn't need to.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. One problem here is that the order of key values (column names) returned by jsonb_object_keys does not match the order of values in array_agg. I wonder if there is a way to address that?

Comment: As a workaround right now I use second query which has where condition set to false, thus executing quickly and returning 0 rows, from which I can then extract column names via ```var columnSchema = await reader.GetColumnSchemaAsync(ct);```. This preserves column name order. In fact, if we did ```array_to_json(array_agg(cte_subquery))``` the order would match as well.

Comment: @NickFarsi Good point, they go out of sync. To keep the 1-roundtrip feature, you can also switch from `array_agg()` to `jsonb_agg()` entirely: the order will be analogous to what `jsonb_object_keys()` outputs, with some added flexibility. You can still read ColumnNames if you want, but you can also see them in the PaginatedEntries and address PaginatedEntries by keys instead of translating keys seen in ColumnNames to indices of key-stripped PaginatedEntries. Added in the edit and the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/y5yRllni)

Comment: Works charmingly, thanks! I just switched ```'{}'::jsonb``` to ```'[]'::jsonb```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
with cte as (select id, name, age, email from dummy_table where false
             union all
             select null::int, null::varchar, null::int, null::varchar from dummy_table
             limit 1)
select
    (select array_agg(column_name) 
       from (select jsonb_object_keys(to_jsonb(cte)) as column_name) 
       as column_names) as "ColumnNames",
    COUNT(*) over() as "TotalCount",
    (select coalesce(array_agg(cte_subquery) filter (where id is not null), '{}') 
       from (select * from cte offset 0 limit 15) as cte_subquery) 
       as "PaginatedEntries",
    3 as "PageNumber",
    15 as "PageSize"
from cte;
```

*Here is an explanation.*

**1.** The trick is here to generate a row with empty values in `cte` query. This can be achieved using `union all` with `null`-values:

```
select id, name, age, email 
from dummy_table 
where false

union all

select null::int, null::varchar, null::int, null::varchar 
from dummy_table
limit 1;
```

As the `cte` query *still generates one row*, the final result will be as follows:

```
     ColumnNames     | TotalCount | PaginatedEntries | PageNumber | PageSize 
---------------------+------------+------------------+------------+----------
 {id,age,name,email} |          1 | {}               |          3 |       15
(1 row)
```

**2.** `TotalCount` is **1** as `cte` generates an "empty" row.

**3.** For `'{}'` value in `PaginatedEntries` column you can modify your query as follows:

```
(select coalesce(array_agg(cte_subquery) filter (where id is not null), '{}') 
 from (select * from cte offset 0 limit 15) as cte_subquery) as "PaginatedEntries"
```

For null values it generates `{}` as a result.

Here is the [demo](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3z2dxbr8p).

Comment: I'm afraid it would be easier to just hardcode these column names somewhere in the caller code then. Next time another query is used in CTE this dummy table and null-row become useless.